# Passing a complex type to a rest service and the standard way to pass parameters to rest services?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

What is the standard way to pass parameters to REST services? Is it `parameterName = value`?

In this way, how would the complex object be passed? I am using c# `WebRequest` class for calling Rest services. Target service could be implemented in any language so the solution I have to implement should be generic.

Answer (score 2):

A very good article about passing complex types has been written by Dave Ward. You can find the article [here](http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/). Also, you can read his recent article about common mistakes while serializing complex types [here](http://encosia.com/2011/04/13/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/).